# action is being dispatched before the state updates

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, action

After `authentication` I am redirected to the dashboard page where I call 3 APIs as soon as I land and then I display the data on it. I am getting the `siteId` from `authentication` page and is available in redux store and set that `siteId` to `dashboard` page's state. The issue is my action is firing before my state gets the value from redux. `MapStateToProps` is firing the action with `undefined`. After the action is fired, the state is being set. If I hard code the state, it works. I tried to check if my state is set before the action is fired, but seems like my check is not working.

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      alarmCount: [],
      workOrderCount: [],
      etaWorkOrder: [],
      countNum: true,
      siteId: this.props.storeNum && this.props.storeNum.siteId
      // siteId: 5260
    }
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getOpenWorkOrdersCount();
    this.props.getEtaWorkOrder();
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps({ alarmCount, workOrderCount, etaWO, storeNum }) {
    if(alarmCount.code) {
        this.setState({ alarmCount: alarmCount.code.data.ticketCount })
    }
    if(workOrderCount) {
      this.setState({ workOrderCount: workOrderCount.data.event.woOutstanding })
    }
    if(etaWO) {
      this.setState({ etaWorkOrder: etaWO.data.woList })
    }
    if(storeNum && storeNum.siteId && !(alarmCount.fetching || alarmCount.success) && !this.state.alarmCount.length){
      this.props.getAlarmCount({siteId: storeNum.siteId});
    }
}


const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      alarmCount: state.alarmCount,
      workOrderCount: state.workOrderCount.count,
      etaWO: state.etaWorkOrder.count,
      storeNum: state.ssoReducer.user
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getAlarmCount: data => dispatch(AlarmCountActions.getAlarmCount({ data }))
});
export default connect( mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard);
```

This is the full component code:

```
class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      alarmCount: [],
      workOrderCount: [],
      etaWorkOrder: [],
      countNum: true,
      // siteId: props.storeNum && props.storeNum.siteId
      siteId: ''
    }
    console.log('<<< storeNum', props.storeNum);
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    // this.props.getOpenWorkOrdersCount();
    // this.props.getEtaWorkOrder();
    // if(this.props.storeNum){
    //   this.props.getAlarmCount(this.props.storeNum.siteId);
    // }
  }
//   componentWillReceiveProps({ alarmCount, workOrderCount, etaWO, storeNum }) {
//     if(alarmCount.code) {
//         this.setState({ alarmCount: alarmCount.code.data.ticketCount })
//     }
//     if(workOrderCount) {
//       this.setState({ workOrderCount: workOrderCount.data.event.woOutstanding })
//     }
//     if(etaWO) {
//       this.setState({ etaWorkOrder: etaWO.data.woList })
//     }
//     if(storeNum){
//       this.setState({ siteId: storeNum.siteId })
//     }
// }

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  console.log('prevProps: ', prevProps)
  if(prevProps.storeNum.siteId !== this.props.storeNum.siteId){
    this.props.getAlarmCount(this.props.storeNum.siteId);
  }
}


todaysDateFormatted = () => {
  let today = new Date();
  let dd = today.getDate();
  let mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
  let yyyy = today.getFullYear();
      if (dd < 10) { dd = '0' + dd }
      if (mm < 10) { mm = '0' + mm }
  return today = mm + '-' + dd + '-' + yyyy;
}
howManyToday = data => {
  let count = 0;
  let todaysDate = this.todaysDateFormatted();
  data.map(item => {
    date = item.eta.replace(/(\d{4})\-(\d{2})\-(\d{2}).*/, '$2-$3-$1')

    if(todaysDate == date)  count++;
  })
  return count;
}
  render() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;
    const woCount = this.state.workOrderCount
    console.log(' ^^^^^^^ storeNuM: ', this.state.siteId)
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.innerBox}>
          <View style={styles.leftBox}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.activeAlarms}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.ALARMS)}>
                <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flex: 1, background: 'transparent'}}>
                  {this.state.countNum ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <Text style={[styles.blueColor, styles.font_24, ]}>{this.state.alarmCount}</Text>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : null}
                  <Text style={[styles.blueColor, styles.font_16] }>Active Alarms</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.openWorkOrders}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.WORK_ORDERS)}>
              <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={[styles.whiteColor, styles.font_24]}>{woCount}</Text>
                <Text style={[styles.whiteColor, styles.font_16]}>Open{'\n'}Work Orders</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.rightBox}>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.todayWorkOrders}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.WORK_ORDERS)}
            >
              <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={[styles.whiteColor, styles.font_24]}>{this.howManyToday(this.state.etaWorkOrder)}</Text> 
                <Text style={[styles.whiteColor, styles.font_16]}>Today ETA{'\n'}Work Orders</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={styles.diyTrainingVideos}
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.TRAINING_VIDEOS)}
            >
              <View style={{ justifyContent: 'flex-end', flex: 1 }}>
                <Text style={[styles.blueColor, styles.font_16]}>DIY{'\n'}Training Videos</Text>
              </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.createWorkOrderBox}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={styles.createBtn}
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.CREATE_WORK_ORDER)}>
            <Text style={styles.workOrderText}>+ WORK ORDER</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
      alarmCount: state.alarmCount,
      workOrderCount: state.workOrderCount.count,
      etaWO: state.etaWorkOrder.count,
      storeNum: state.ssoReducer.user
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getEtaWorkOrder: () => dispatch(etaWorkOrderActions.etaWorkOrder()),
  getOpenWorkOrdersCount: () => dispatch(WorkOrderCountActions.count()),
  getAlarmCount: data => dispatch(AlarmCountActions.getAlarmCount({ data })),
  logoutUser: () => dispatch(logoutAction.logoutUser())
});
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)(Dashboard);
```

What is wrong with my check? ComponentWillReceiveProps is firing the action now, I had ComponentDidMount fire the action before, that did not work either. How can I make sure that my state is set before `this.props.getAlarmCount({siteId: storeNum.siteId})` is fired?

Comment: Where is your `render`? Is there a reason you're using component state and not just props? Generally speaking you don't want to initialize your state with props because (if not handled properly) it could cause undesired behavior when the component rerenders

Comment: I'm confused, why does `siteId` need to be stored in your local state? Also you're passing `{data: { siteId: storeNum.siteId }` to your action creator which doesn't seem right, but I'm just guessing. Seems like you could just use `componentDidUpdate` and check `if(prevProps.storeNum.siteId !== this.props.storeNum.siteId)` and then make your call

Comment: @Galupuf I just cutout the render part(the code is too big) that was rendering what I was getting from the response. Do you mean to use like this: 
```if(this.props.storeNum){
      this.props.getAlarmCount(this.props.storeNum.siteId);
    }```

Comment: Essentially yes. You should make your api call in `componentDidMount`. Just pass the props directly into that api call. I don't see a need for component level state.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak If I can pass siteId to ```this.props. getAlarmCount``` without setting it to the state - that would also work for me, I use this state only to pass them as arguments to fire actions. I have tried the code you recommended, I am not even seeing my console statement, looks like that isn't firing.

Comment: @Galupuf  ```componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getOpenWorkOrdersCount();
    this.props.getEtaWorkOrder();
    if(this.props.storeNum){ 
      this.props.getAlarmCount(this.props.storeNum.siteId); 
    }
  }``` 
did not work. I think ```ComponentDidMount``` is firing before ```mapStateToProps``` gets the value from the store.

Comment: If the component is mounted before the value is present in your store, then yes that won't work.

Comment: @Galupuf Is there any way to delay the mounting of Dashboard component before the value is available in the store since my checks are being ignored inside ```ComponentDidMount``` on Dashboard page? I think either component mounting needs to be delayed or ```ComponentDidMount``` firing needs to be delayed. But for that we have the ```if/else``` checks right?

Comment: You can put this in the parent components render:

    `{
      this.props.storeNum && <Dashbaord />
    }`
Then the component won't be rendered until you have the variable you need

Comment: Another thing that's worth mentioning is that you don't need to pass state to your action creator; If you use `redux-thunk` you can have access to your store inside your action creator.

Comment: Did you try putting `this.props.getAlarmCount({siteId: storeNum.siteId});` in `componenDidMount()`

Comment: Inside componentDidMount, try adding a callback to setState ` this.setState({ siteId: this.props.storeNum.siteId }, () => this.props.getAlarmCount({ siteId : this.state.siteId} ))`

Comment: @VuHuuCuong yes, unfortunately did not, I am probably missing some important point here. The logic seems right to me.

Comment: ```componentDidMount() {
      this.props.getOpenWorkOrdersCount();
      this.props.getEtaWorkOrder();
     // this.props.getAlarmCount({siteId: this.state.siteId}); 
    if(this.props.storeNum){
      this.setState({ 
        siteId: this.props.storeNum.siteId 
      }, 
      () => this.props.getAlarmCount({ siteId : this.state.siteId} ))
    }
  }``` did not do the trick, I put a console after `if` statement, that didnt fire at all.

Comment: @Galupuf I am using redux-saga, is there a way to access the store inside `mapDispatchToProps`? in this example: ```const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  getAlarmCount: data => dispatch(AlarmCountActions.getAlarmCount({ data }))
});``` When I console.log the `dispatch` object it only return function names.